# Parcellite does not want to start on boot?

Tags: 15.04

I am using Ubuntu 15.04 and have set up that parcellite starts on boot by adding the command `parcellite` in the Startup Applications section.

However, it does not start when I reboot the system?

It's odd because all other apps start on boot this way. I never had such issues with any app. I cannot even understand how it cannot start because when I enter `parcellite` in the Terminal, the Parcellite starts regularly.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 16.04.

I think when installing parcellite has automatically created the Startup Applications entry, which simply started parcellite. So basically it was running (I saw a process in System Monitor), but it was not working: i.e. no icon in the Panel and the keyboard shortcuts did not work.

Starting it from the terminal directly worked. But starting it from the sh shell didn't. Has anyone an idea why?

Anyway. The way I "fixed" this is to start the parcellite command in the bash shell: here's the command that I've now used in the Startup Application:

```
bash -c "parcellite &"
```

Comment: I had to made the command sleep for a few seconds before launching it for some reason.